# Numpy array loss of dimension when masking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to select certain elements of an array and perform a weighted average calculation based on the values. However, using a filter condition, destroys the original structure of the array. `arr` which was of shape `(2, 2, 3, 2)` is turned into a 1-dimensional array. This is of no use to me, as not all these elements need to be combined later on with each other (but subarrays of them). How can I avoid this flattening?

```
>>> arr = np.asarray([ [[[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33]], [[4, 44], [5, 55], [6, 66]]], [ [[7, 77], [8, 88], [9, 99]], [[0, 32], [1, 33], [2, 34] ]] ])
>>> arr
array([[[[ 1, 11],
         [ 2, 22],
         [ 3, 33]],

        [[ 4, 44],
         [ 5, 55],
         [ 6, 66]]],


       [[[ 7, 77],
         [ 8, 88],
         [ 9, 99]],

        [[ 0, 32],
         [ 1, 33],
         [ 2, 34]]]])
>>> arr.shape
(2, 2, 3, 2)
>>> arr[arr>3]
array([11, 22, 33,  4, 44,  5, 55,  6, 66,  7, 77,  8, 88,  9, 99, 32, 33,
       34])
>>> arr[arr>3].shape
(18,)
```

Comment: Elaborate on the calculation that you need to do with these values.  How would you use the `arr` structure?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Checkout `numpy.where`

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

To keep the same dimensionality you are going to need a fill value. In the example below I use 0, but you could also use `np.nan`

```
np.where(arr>3, arr, 0)
```

returns

```
array([[[[ 0, 11],
         [ 0, 22],
         [ 0, 33]],

        [[ 4, 44],
         [ 5, 55],
         [ 6, 66]]],


       [[[ 7, 77],
         [ 8, 88],
         [ 9, 99]],

        [[ 0, 32],
         [ 0, 33],
         [ 0, 34]]]])
```

Answer (score 13):

You might consider using an [`np.ma.masked_array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) to represent the subset of elements that satisfy your condition:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([[[[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33]],
                   [[4, 44], [5, 55], [6, 66]]],
                  [[[7, 77], [8, 88], [9, 99]],
                   [[0, 32], [1, 33], [2, 34]]]])

masked_arr = np.ma.masked_less(arr, 3)

print(masked_arr)
# [[[[-- 11]
#    [-- 22]
#    [3 33]]

#   [[4 44]
#    [5 55]
#    [6 66]]]


#  [[[7 77]
#    [8 88]
#    [9 99]]

#   [[-- 32]
#    [-- 33]
#    [-- 34]]]]
```

As you can see, the masked array retains its original dimensions. You can access the underlying data and the mask via the `.data` and `.mask` attributes respectively. Most numpy functions will not take into account masked values, e.g.:

```
# mean of whole array
print(arr.mean())
# 26.75

# mean of non-masked elements only
print(masked_arr.mean())
# 33.4736842105
```

The result of an element-wise operation on a masked array and a non-masked array will also preserve the values of the mask:

```
masked_arrsum = masked_arr + np.random.randn(*arr.shape)

print(masked_arrsum)
# [[[[-- 11.359989067421582]
#    [-- 23.249092437269162]
#    [3.326111354088174 32.679132708120726]]

#   [[4.289134334263137 43.38559221094378]
#    [6.028063054523145 53.5043991898567]
#    [7.44695154979811 65.56890530368757]]]


#  [[[8.45692625294376 77.36860675985407]
#    [5.915835159196378 87.28574554110307]
#    [8.251106168209688 98.7621940026713]]

#   [[-- 33.24398289945855]
#    [-- 33.411941757624284]
#    [-- 34.964817895873715]]]]
```

The sum is only computed over the non-masked values of `masked_arr` - you can see this by looking at `masked_sum.data`:

```
print(masked_sum.data)
# [[[[  1.          11.35998907]
#    [  2.          23.24909244]
#    [  3.32611135  32.67913271]]

#   [[  4.28913433  43.38559221]
#    [  6.02806305  53.50439919]
#    [  7.44695155  65.5689053 ]]]


#  [[[  8.45692625  77.36860676]
#    [  5.91583516  87.28574554]
#    [  8.25110617  98.762194  ]]

#   [[  0.          33.2439829 ]
#    [  1.          33.41194176]
#    [  2.          34.9648179 ]]]]
```

Comment: I was tossing up between your's and `np.where`. I went with it because it suits the purpose in a single line of code. It seemed like the best fit. All were good answers...

Answer (score 5):

Look at `arr>3`:

```
In [71]: arr>3
Out[71]: 
array([[[[False,  True],
         [False,  True],
         [False,  True]],

        [[ True,  True],
         [ True,  True],
         [ True,  True]]],


       [[[ True,  True],
         [ True,  True],
         [ True,  True]],

        [[False,  True],
         [False,  True],
         [False,  True]]]], dtype=bool)
```

`arr[arr>3]` selects those elements where the mask is `True`.  What kind of structure or shape do you want that selection to have?  Flat is the only thing that makes sense, doesn't it?  `arr` itself is not changed.

You could zero out the terms that don't fit the mask,

```
In [84]: arr1=arr.copy()
In [85]: arr1[arr<=3]=0
In [86]: arr1
Out[86]: 
array([[[[ 0, 11],
         [ 0, 22],
         [ 0, 33]],

        [[ 4, 44],
         [ 5, 55],
         [ 6, 66]]],


       [[[ 7, 77],
         [ 8, 88],
         [ 9, 99]],

        [[ 0, 32],
         [ 0, 33],
         [ 0, 34]]]])
```

Now you could do weight sums or averages over various dimensions.

`np.nonzero` (or `np.where`) might also be useful, giving you the indices of the the selected terms:

```
In [88]: np.nonzero(arr>3)
Out[88]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]),
 array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you on the other hand need the minimum value to be replaced in place of the values less than the value that you check for (`3` in  your example), then you can use [**numpy.clip()**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) or [**ndarray.clip()**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.clip.html):

```
In [27]: np.clip(arr, 3, np.max(arr))
Out[27]: 
array([[[[ 3, 11],
         [ 3, 22],
         [ 3, 33]],

        [[ 4, 44],
         [ 5, 55],
         [ 6, 66]]],


       [[[ 7, 77],
         [ 8, 88],
         [ 9, 99]],

        [[ 3, 32],
         [ 3, 33],
         [ 3, 34]]]])
```

Answer (score -4):

CLEARLY what you need 2 do is first re—shape the array and then convert like so:

```
maschked_data = data[:,0][np.zeros(np.reshape(data, -1), np.reshape(data, -1).shape[0])[:,0].shape[0]]
```

data[:,0] <3