# Select elements of numpy array via mask and preserving original dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I have following data

```
ids = np.concatenate([1.0 * np.ones(shape=(4, 9,)), 
                      2.0 * np.ones(shape=(4, 3,))], axis=1)

logits = np.random.normal(size=(4, 9 + 3, 256))
```

Now I want to get numpy array only of ids that have 1.0 and I want to get array of size `(4,9, 256)`

I tried `logits[ids == 1.0, :]` but I get `(36, 256)`
How I can make slicing without connecting first two dimensions ?

Current dimensions are only example ones and I am looking for generic solution.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible as it is. But you can fill the value where conditon doesn't get satisfied with something else such that it doesn't affect your further processing. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046162/numpy-array-loss-of-dimension-when-masking

Comment: In your example, you are only masking the 2nd dimension.  So you could reduce the mask to a 1d array: `logits[:,(ids==1.0).all(axis=0),:]`.  It's up to you to supply the added information about the distribution of `True`, whether that means `reshape` after, or modifying the mask before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears to assume that each row has the same number of nonzero entries; in that case you can solve your problem generally like this:

```python
mask = (ids == 1)
num_per_row = mask.sum(1)

# same number of entries per row is required
assert np.all(num_per_row == num_per_row[0])  

result = logits[mask].reshape(logits.shape[0], num_per_row[0], logits.shape[2])

print(result.shape)
# (4, 9, 256)
```