# Pytorch tensor loss of dimension when masking

Tags: pytorch, tensor

> Just to be upfront, this is basically the same question as [Numpy array loss of dimension when masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046162/numpy-array-loss-of-dimension-when-masking), but for PyTorch tensors rather than NumPy arrays. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046530/1862861)(s) to that question, using the equivalent PyTorch function [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html) or [masked tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/masked.html) work, but I found that a Google search about this for PyTorch tensors did not quickly hit upon an answer. So, I thought an equivalent StackOverflow [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) tagged question might be useful for others!)

I have a 2D PyTorch tensor (although it could have more dimensions) to which I want to apply an equivalently shaped binary mask. However, when I apply the mask the output is just 1-dimensional. How can I keep the same dimensions as the original tensor after application of the mask?

E.g., for

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[1.0, 2.0, 8.0], [-4.0, 0.0, 3.0]])
mask = x >=2.0
print(x[mask])
tensor([2., 8., 3.])
```

the output is now 1D rather than 2D.

Comment: maybe I do not understand the question well, but `torch.where(mask, x, 0)` does preserve the dimension, and replace the "filtered out" value by 0

Comment: Yes, that does work, which I say in the blurb at the start of the question. I meant to also add that as an/the answer, but hadn't got round to it yet. Feel free to post the answer yourself. I mainly posted the question as (hopefully) an aid to others searching for the same information.

Comment: makes sense. I guess a community answer in this case would be the best

Answer (score 1):

Using `torch`'s `where` function we'll get the row, column `tensors` like:

```
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[1.0, 2.0, 8.0], [-4.0, 0.0, 3.0]])
mask = x >=2.0
print(torch.where(mask))
print(x[torch.where(mask)])
```

Which outputs:

```
(tensor([0, 0, 1]), tensor([1, 2, 2]))
tensor([2., 8., 3.])
```

However, plugging that into `x` will output only the `mask`ed values leaving us with a 1D `tensor` because we're getting rid of all the values in the `tensor` that don't evaluate to `True` (so it can't be the same shape as its original `tensor` because it has fewer values so it gets flattened into a single dimension).

If you want `x` to be its original shape but *only* `where` `mask`ed values are `Truth`y then we could fill a `tensor` of zeros with ones at those indexes:

```
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[1.0, 2.0, 8.0], [-4.0, 0.0, 3.0]])
mask = x >=2.0
masked_x = torch.zeros((x.shape))
masked_x[torch.where(mask)] = 1.0
print(masked_x)
```

Outputs:

```
tensor([[0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

So now `masked_x` is a `tensor` of zeros the same shape as `x` but with ones `where` the `mask` is `Truth`y.

If you want `masked_x` to comprise of `x`'s values `where` the `mask` is `Truth`y then:

```
masked_x = torch.zeros((x.shape))
masked_x[torch.where(mask)] = x[torch.where(mask)]
print(masked_x)
```

Outputs:

```
tensor([[0., 2., 8.],
        [0., 0., 3.]])
```

a `tensor` of zeros `where` `mask` was `False`y.

If you want something else, please clarify.

Comment: You can simplify the use of `where` by just doing `torch.where(mask, x, 0)`, which gives your final result.

Comment: @Matt Pitkin I kept it like how I would do it with `numpy`'s `where` just for demonstration purposes/keeping it simple but good point!

Answer (score 1):

Just like suggested in the [numpy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046162/numpy-array-loss-of-dimension-when-masking), `torch.where` will do the trick.

> To keep the same dimensionality you are going to need a fill value. In the example below I use 0, but you could also use **torch**.nan

```py
torch.where(mask, x, 0)
```

returns

```py
tensor([[0., 2., 8.],
        [0., 0., 3.]])
```